# how to get the value in jquery from unknown type element

Tags: jquery

in my page i want to get the value of a div or textbox.

in two different different condition he can be div and textbox it is sure

how i can get the value of div or textbox when i am sure that it was only div or textbox but not sure that it was div or textbox.

any method can help me to get the value even he was div or textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $el = $('#element'),
    value = $el.val() || $el.text();
```

The second line will use .text() if .val() is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

[One solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/ahraX/2/) is to use the `.is(':text')` [filter](http://api.jquery.com/is/)+[selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/):

```
var elm = $('divOrInput'),
    text = '';
if (elm.is(':text')) {
    text = elm.val();
} else {
    text = elm.text();
}
```

Or, condensed:

```
var elm = $('divOrInput');
var text = elm.is(':text') ? elm.val() : elm.text();
```

---

**EDIT**

My [previous "solution"](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/ahraX/) *didn't* work! Or, it did, but that was because the `.text()` works on `<textarea>`, too. *If* OP is talking about a `<textarea>` just use `.text()` on both. If, on the other hand, OP is talking about `<input type="text" ... />` vs. `<div>` the solution presented here can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function works on textareas as well as divs:

```
<div id="myDiv">some text</div>
<textarea id="myTextarea">some more text</textarea>

$('#myDiv').html(); // works
$('#myTextarea').html(); // works
```

This means that you can use `.html()` without knowing which type of element your element is.

---

**Edit**

If you mean it could be an `input` or a `div`, you can use the `nodeName` property:

```
<div id="textbox">some text</div>
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="some more text">
```

This jQuery will give you the result on either:

```
var $el = $('#textbox'),
    content;

content = ($el[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div') ? $el.html() : $el.val();
```

Comment: Nice solution, although the `.html()` will ... preserve the HTML in the `<div>` (if any): [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/ahraX/1/).

Comment: @jensgram True, but it's difficult to tell from the question whether this is a good thing or a bad thing...

Answer (score 0):

Check the tagName. HTML:

```
<div class="foo">This is div content.</div>
<textarea class="foo">This is textarea content.</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log( $('.foo:first')[0].tagName.toLowerCase() );
console.log( $('.foo:last')[0].tagName.toLowerCase() );
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3DS6/).

---

I kept messing with the fiddle and ended up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abackstrom/H3DS6/1/):

```
$.fn.footext = function() {
    var tagName = $(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (tagName == 'div') {
        return $(this).text();
    } else if (tagName == 'textarea') {
        return $(this).val();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};

console.log($('.foo:first').footext());
console.log($('.foo:last').footext());
```